# Magento error in search with attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-enterprise, search

This is the sample search attributes parameter in url:

> zip_code=123456&tire_cities=1&tire_state=1

If any one of attributes matches then search result is displayed. If first attributes are correct and rest are false then also results displayed.

What I want is I need to display result if all attributes are true else no result shown be shown.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: if you are talking about catalog search then by default it checks for all the conditions.

Comment: if all 1 of 4 conditions is true then also search result is seen with product. It should show if all condition is true else no. means just changing OR condition to AND